# Atualizar tabela após Inserir em outra

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela chamada Consumo, nessa tabela tenho uma coluna Quantidade.
Tenho outra tabela chamada Produto, nessa tabela tenho uma coluna Estoque.

Sempre que um novo consumo for inserido, deve-se escolher um produto e a quantidade que foi consumida daquele produto.

Preciso fazer uma trigger onde a cada consumo feito diminui o estoque do produto escolhido de acordo com a quantidade informada.
Exemplo: Produto 1 tem 10 em estoque. Consumo do Produto 1, 2 quantidades.
Atualizar o estoque do produto 1 para 8.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não cheguei a conclusão de nenhum código. Obrigado.

Comment: Esta trabalhando com qual bando de dados? MySQL?

Comment: Procure por Trigger

Comment: Estou usando o Sql Server

Comment: uma `trigger` não garante que o valor vá ser mesmo atualizado, me parece um processo transacional, já pensou em atualizar tudo dentro de uma `transaction` para garantir?

Comment: Está trabalhando com qual Servidor? C#?

Comment: Não cheguei a ver transaction

Comment: Estou trabalhando com C#, porém preciso disso no Sql Server

Comment: Ou você trabalha com Trigger, ou você implementa a solução em C#, nem tem outra alternativa.

Comment: o certo nessa situação seria trigger, maaaaaaas, faz uma tabela de estoque cara... simplifica muito

Comment: tabela: `movimento_estoque`
...
`produto | valor | quantidade | saldo_anterior | saldo_atual`

nessa tabela só faz inserts, nenhum update. Assim você mantém todo o histórico de movimentação;

Comment: Consegui resolver com trigger, vou postar o código

Comment: @RicardoPontual, acho que por padrão os triggers tem uma transação implícita. Se der erro no update, o insert também não seria executado

Comment: interessante @DiegoRafaelSouza vou dar uma pesquisada, valeu

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER DiminuirEstoque
ON Consumo
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PRODUTO SET ESTOQUE = ESTOQUE - C.QUANTIDADE
    FROM INSERTED C JOIN PRODUTO P ON C.CODIGOPRODUTO = P.CODIGO
END
```

Acho que fica melhor assim

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com a seguinte Trigger

```
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER DiminuirEstoque
ON Consumo
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @qtdEstoque int
    select @qtdEstoque = Quantidade from Inserted
    declare @codigoProduto int
    select @codigoProduto = CodigoProduto from Inserted
    Update Produto set Estoque = (Select Estoque from Produto where Codigo = @codigoProduto) - @qtdEstoque where Codigo = @codigoProduto
END
```